# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC + EF Core 2 or Angular 5

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I don't want to solicit a debate. The question is more, "Can I achieve the same results using ASP.NET Core 2 MVC + EF Core 2 vs Angular 5, and if this is possible with Angular 5, how (high level)?"

I don't know a lot about Angular 5, and I have only started designing very small web apps in ASP.NET Core a few months ago.

My application involves:
- A Relational Database (~50 tables, includes all flavours of relationships), as well as another proprietary database, and perform CRUD statements on both.
- Users must authenticate themselves via Log In and maintain this authentication as they work within the App. Different Login Privileges cause different behaviour in the app.
- More than one Model's Data being involved in a View (necessitating View Models).
- Users need to be able to dynamically add Controls to the App to submit multiple data sets in one operation (via JavaScript).
- In one View, Users need to be able to post data back and receive a response from the database without refreshing the web page. Basically, all of their work in this View would be done without reloading the web page (AJAX?).
- Users, at least on the desktop, need to receive updates from the server when the data they are looking at has changed (via another user) (again AJAX, I believe).
- The app should work one way on a desktop browser and another way on a mobile browser display (Bootstrap?).

Perhaps I am hung up on the hype behind Angular 5, with it's promise to achieve "Rich, Flowing Client-Side Web Apps". Is it just more work to create a nice Client-Side experience with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't say that this is a question of "ASP.NET Core 2 MVC + EF Core 2 vs Angular 5". Your approach will be that of either:

- Server-side delivered pages (MVC), or
- Client-side rendered pages (Angular).

Both cases you will need ASP.NET Core and EF Core. In the first case, you'll use ASP.NET Core with the MVC packages and use Razor to generate and render your markup on the server and send it to the client. In the second case, you won't need MVC but you'll need other packages to support a REST Web API on ASP.NET Core to provide the data for your client-side Angular app.

The shift these days is definitely towards using static, SPA on the client (Angular/React/Vue) with an API/s on the server-side. There's caveats you need to be aware of though in terms of SEO, additional complexity, in-house skills to achieve it and so on.

So if you're willing to take on the learning curve and take on a more modern approach you can try out Angular with APIs on the backend, but to be honest it could be easier to just use traditional MVC and sprinkle some Vue.js with AJAX on the front-end to drive some of the dynamic UI (dynamic form and data updates).

To address your points in order:

- DB, if you're familiar with it I'd use EF Core, it's well supported and highly productive. Just be aware of the performance overhead it creates if that's an issue.
- Authentication/Authorization, the default ASP.NET Core templates offer some of this, otherwise check out [Auth0](https://auth0.com) for a IDaaS (ID as a Service) platform you can leverage.
- Dynamic controls, you can use some pretty basic plain JavaScript here to create the additional form fields on the fly. I'd use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) though for its simplicity and plug-n-play nature.
- One view that can submit data and not refresh, again AJAX is your friend. Axios is a nice, modern AJAX library that's well supported. Or you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (with polyfills for older browsers)
- Dynamic page updates, this is what is commonly called "Subscriptions" in development. Modern browsers/servers support [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), a persistent connection between client and server allowing the server to push data to the client. Preferred over polling for performance reasons. Check out [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr), made by the ASP.NET Core team to do this well cross-browser. They're currently working on a 2.1 release.
- Tailored desktop/mobile UIs, yes this is responsive web design (RWD). It has limitations you'll need to be aware of, mostly from the fact that the same HTML is typically served up to both devices and the CSS can only style that within it's control. Bootstrap is a UI framework (HTML snippets + CSS) that makes RWD much easier by giving you a responsive grid for building your layout and a library of components to use.

In summary, either approach will work it just takes a bit of upfront consideration as to the pros/cons of each and more importantly the timeline/skills you or your team have to pull it off. There's plenty of information online if you search for "ASP.NET MVC vs SPA".

Comment: Thank you. Very thorough. I had no idea about the concept of WebSockets used with browsers, so I will look into SignalR. These are apps for internal purposes so SEO is not in scope. This was a great answer to open up doors of learning!